# Is there way to count if one or both columns haven't been filled?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

I am hoping to edit my current spreadsheet that is using

`="To evaluate: "&IF(COUNTIFS(Worker,"M",Status,"Closed",Date_closed,">=1/9/2020",Outcome,"",Feeling,"")>0,"M: "&COUNTIFS(Worker,"M",Status,"Closed",Date_closed,">=1/9/2020",Outcome,"",Feeling,"")&"; ",""`

Currently this is only counting when both sections aren't filled (Outcome/Feeling). I would like it to work so even when one hasn't been filled, it is still adding to the count by 1

Your assistance is so welcome as I am stuck on this issue!

Many Thanks,
Excel Rookie

Answer (score 0):

You can merge your criteria into one: `="To evaluate: "&IF(COUNTIFS(Worker,"M",Status,"Closed",Date_closed,">=1/9/2020",OR(Outcome="",Feeling=""),TRUE)>0,"M: "&COUNTIFS(Worker,"M",Status,"Closed",Date_closed,">=1/9/2020",OR(Outcome="",Feeling=""),TRUE)&"; ",""`
You may have to create an additional column, for cleaner understanding or when `OR` condition gets too complicated

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will be testing this now.

Comment: Will this differentiate between having 1 blank rather than needing both to have a positive? I.E. adding 1 to the count when only 1 column has not been filled?

Comment: @ExcelAdvice, yes this will count when at least one of `Outcome` or `Feeling` is filled. However it will not check whether content is positive. Is that in fact your expectation?